# React and Authorization using an API

Tags: reactjs, authentication

Curious about calling APIs from the browser and authentication using react client-side.

If you were to build an app using react, calling an existing API which is expecting to receive an authentication token in the HTTP header. What are some libraries that I could look at to handle this for me.

Failing that what is the best approach to do so, if at all. If not, why?

Comment: Did you take a look at JWT authentication? 
https://davidwalsh.name/react-authentication

Comment: @radix I did come across the Auth0 but what I found was going on more about the whole social media auth which is not what I wanted, this is good thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `JWT` tokens you can use `jwt-decode` - https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode. Basically you can use this to parse the token and get all the information contained within it.

When you login, you will receive the token which you can store in `storage` or a `redux` variable and then when you make API calls just add it to the `header`. `jwt-decode` can be used to get information about the user etc from the token.